# Javamail : Setting timeout for folder.search

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, imap

I have been using Javamail (version 1.6.4)  for a while now, mostly for event listening, mail parsing and copy/delete mails (from Exchnage using IMAPS). Lately i was asked to use sub-folders for a business usecase. When moving mail from the Inbox folder to a sub-folder the UID changes so i'm using folder.search() in order to find the new UID. This works most of the times but sometimes the search goes indefnitley (or its duration is very long) which may lag the entire application.

1. Is there a way to set a timeout (or other way to throw an exception if it runs too long) for folder.search()?
2. I understood that imap search is done on the server side but i just wanted to validate. this is an example of how i send search to the server (we can assume subject is unique for this discussion):

```
private static String findMailIdBySubject(String mailbox, String srcFolder, String subject) {
        Folder srcFolderObj = null;
        boolean wasConnectionEstablished = connectToMail(mailbox);

        if (!wasConnectionEstablished) {
            return null;
        }
        // get mailboxStore object
        MailboxStore mailboxStore = MailBoxStoreList.getMailStoreByMailBox(mailbox);
        try {
            // Open inbox folder to get messages metadata
            srcFolderObj = mailboxStore.getStore().getFolder(srcFolder);
            srcFolderObj.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            // create search Term
            SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 7L;

                @Override
                public boolean match(Message message) {
                    try {
                        String mailSubject = message.getSubject();
                        if (mailSubject == null) {
                            mailSubject = "";
                        }
                        if (mailSubject.equals(subject)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                        log.error("Failed to search for mail with mailbox: " + mailbox + " in folder: " + srcFolder
                                + " subject: " + subject + " Error: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
            // search for the relevant message
            Message[] messages = srcFolderObj.search(term);
            UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder) srcFolderObj;
            return String.valueOf(uf.getUID(messages[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Subject: Failed to find id of mail in mailbox " + mailbox + " in folder " + srcFolder
                    + "  , Error: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (srcFolderObj != null && srcFolderObj.isOpen()) {
                    srcFolderObj.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

i also tried to replace SearchTerm override with the following but performance was the same:

```
SearchTerm searchTerm = new SubjectTerm(subject);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't look like a server-side search; that java code has to stay on the client. Check [what IMAP commands are sent](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug), what you want is a single `uid search` command and not any `uid fetch`.

Comment: hi @arnt i dont have the UID that is why i'm looking for it (i have the all the other metadata), i will try to use the debug to see which commands are being sent to the server.

Comment: It's possible that you may see a command such as `uid fetch 1:* …` in the log, and a staggeringly large set of responses.

Comment: Also, assuming your server supports UIDPLUS (most do), the new UID should be available as part of the `UID COPY` or `UID MOVE` response.  You might want to check the documentation to see if this response is available to you.  For example, it looks like `IMAPFolder.copyUIDMessages()` can return an array of “AppendUIDs” which are the UIDs in the destination folder.  Also see `moveUIDMessages()`

Comment: Hi @Max, that sound very promising i will test it. Thanks